# Pandas to_sql() CREATE TABLE permission denied

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to write a df to an existing table with pandas.to_sql with this code:

```
import sqlalchemy 

#CREATE CONNECTION
constring = "mssql+pyodbc://UID:PASSWORD@SERVER/DATABASE?driver=SQL Server"
dbEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(constring, fast_executemany=True, connect_args={'connect_timeout':10}, echo=False)

#WRITE INTO TABLE
df.to_sql(con=dbEngine, schema="dbo", name="target_table", if_exists="replace", index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'database'. (262) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE [target_table] (
[chLocalIndustryCode] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[vcLocalIndustryDesc] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[chLocalSectorCode] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[vcLocalSectorDesc] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[chLocalClusterCode] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[vcLocalClusterDesc] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[chLocalMegaClusterCode] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
[vcLocalMegaClusterDesc] VARCHAR(max) NULL)
]

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I have checked the connection and works properly when reading the table , so I assume the problem is with pandas to_sql() function. I have also tried writing into the table with a cursor, but takes to long.

I am using pandas 1.3.4

Is there any way of fixing this error or any alternative to pd.to_sql() function that I can use to increase writing speed?

Comment: you seems to don't have permission to write in database "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'database'" try to modify permissions and you should do normaly what you want to do. Generaly you will need administrator permissions to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add create permission to the SQL Server user. You can follow below steps from the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5280021/CREATE-DATABASE-permission-denied-in-database-mast):

> To add a Windows user that has the login “domainname \username” to the
> sysadmin fixed server role
>
> a. Log on to the computer using the credentials for the
> domainname\username account.
>
> b. Click the Start button, point to All Programs, click Microsoft SQL
> Server, right-click SQL Server Management Studio, and then click Run
> as administrator. ps: "Run As Administrator" option elevates the user
> permissions In the User Access Control dialog box, click Continue.
>
> c. In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to an instance of SQL
> Server.
>
> d. Click Security, right-click Logins, and then click New Login.
>
> e. In the Login name box, enter the user name.
>
> f. In the Select a page pane, click Server Roles, select the sysadmin
> check box, and then click OK.

Comment: Are there any alternatives that do not involve elevating the permissions in the SQL Server? This is a perfectly valid solution to my question, but I am on a corporate server and I just want to know if there is a less bureaucratic solution to this problem.